# How can I center an integer variable in a string?

Tags: python, string, centering

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
   Time        Distance
----------    ----------
    1              100
    2              200
```

I've tried:

```
count = 1
print('   Hour   ' + '\t' + ' Distance ')
print('----------' + '\t' + '----------')
while count <= timeTraveled:
print(str.center(10[str(count)]) + '\t' + str.center(10[str((speedOfVehicle * count))]))
count = count + 1
```

No matter how much I try to make my variables a string for formatting purposes I always encounter:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: What did you expect e.g. `10[str(count)]` to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, 10 is the space amount. count is the integer variable amount. I want count to be printed as a string and centered within the 10 spaces specified.

Comment: @GOD kindly post the full code. How do you get speedOfVehicle where is it defined; so that community can help you write a python code.

Comment: But 1. that's not the right syntax for any of Python's string formatting; and 2. that's also not actually inside a string template, you're trying to run it as code. Maybe [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem: you've mistaken the meta-syntax of [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_center.htm) for Python syntax.

When a document describes a command with optional fields, brackets denote the option parts.  This description style is at least 45 years old, dating back to the days when IBM drove all things computer in the western hemisphere.  For help in writing your command, see the examples farther down.

In your case, you need something like

```
print(str(count).center(10))
```

This is a *method* of the string class; it operates on the string with which you call it.  In your case, that string is `str(count)`.  Can you follow the rest from there?